# How to fix 'object is possibly undefined' and why do I get this error at all?

Tags: javascript, typescript, undefined, fetch-api

So Typescript underlines  **this.ratesMap.get(rate[0])** and tells it's probably undefined. Adding ! solves the problem, I don't get the error anymore but the code just won't work, the output is empty and there's no other errors in the terminal and in the console.

Why typescript underlines **this.ratesMap.get(rate[0])** and not **this.ratesMap.has(rate[0])**? How can I fix this?

```
export class CardStore implements ICardStore {
  public lastRates: ICard[] = [];

  @observable
  public cardsArray: CurrencyCard[] = []

  @observable
  private ratesMap: Map<string, CurrencyCard> = new Map<string, CurrencyCard>();
  
  public constructor(@inject(CardApi) private api: CardApi) {
    makeObservable(this);
    this.getRates();
    this.updateRate();
  }

  @computed
  public get recentRates(): CurrencyCard[] {
    return this.cardsArray = [...this.ratesMap.values()]
  }

  private async getRates() {
    const rates = await this.api.loadRates();
    runInAction(() => {
      Object.entries(rates).forEach((rate) => {
        if (this.ratesMap.has(rate[0])) {
          this.ratesMap.get(rate[0]).update(rate[1]);
        } else {
          let newCard = new CurrencyCard(rate[0], rate[1]);
          this.ratesMap.set(rate[0], newCard);
        }
      });    
    });
  }
```

**loadrates()** from the code above is here:

```
        public async loadRates(): Promise<Record<string, number>> {
            return await fetch(
                `https://freecurrencyapi.net/api/v2/latest?apikey=MYAPIKEY&base_currency=USD`
            )
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => (data.data)); 
            }
}
```

Comment: You need to check if its undefined or not before using it. For example, with an if condition. These types of warnings are great because they remind you that your code could break if the object is ever undefined for some reason.

Comment: It can be `undefined` if `rates[0]` is not the `ratesMap`

Answer (score 1):

The return value of the `get` method of `Map` can be `undefined` (if the map doesn't have an entry for that key). TypeScript doesn't know that you've guarded against that with a `has` call.

Instead, don't use `has` (doing `has`+`get` is generally an antipattern anyway [a mostly harmless one ], it forces traversal of the map twice). Get the card and check if you got one:

```
private async getRates() {
  const rates = await this.api.loadRates();
  runInAction(() => {
    Object.entries(rates).forEach((rate) => {
      const card = this.ratesMap.get(rate[0]);  // ***
      if (card) {                               // ***
        card.update(rate[1]);                   // ***
      } else {
        let newCard = new CurrencyCard(rate[0], rate[1]);
        this.ratesMap.set(rate[0], newCard);
      }
    });    
  });
}
```

TypeScript will be able to narrow the type of `card` based on `if (card)`, so it will know `card` is not `undefined` in the body of the `if` and will let you use `update` on it.